# Get decimal value of an ipv6 address

Tags: excel, decimal, calculator, ipv6

Could anyone help me with the formula to calculate the decimal value of an IPv6 address?

I need to put the formula in VBA to make a custom excel formula. I know the formula for IPv4 and I have read it is similar but I can not seem to figure it out. I need this to be able to map a IPv6 address to a range in the `ip2location` CSV.

Comment: Well you can figure it out from the fact that IPv6 address are 8 values of 16-bits. So you work out the polynomial with powers of 65536 (2^16). It's going to be one big, honkin' number. If you need more than that, just Google "IPv6 to decimal conversion". Lots of hits.

Comment: It really is like the IPv4 case, but with IPv6 you have powers of 65536 instead of 255, and you have 8 terms instead of 4.

Comment: Ok but when i use a calculator and compare to the ip2location csv I get the correct result. if i change the ipv4 formula to 8 terms and multiply by powers of 65536 instead of 256 I get a completely different number then what the calculator or the csv give me. so i make a mistake somewhere but i dont know where..

Comment: Excel maxes out at about 15-16 significant digits. You need up to approximately 40 significant digits to represent an IPv6 number as a decimal in Excel. The value of `65536^7` requires 34 significant digits.

Answer (score 0):

A decimal value of an IPv6 address would be to big. You would need a 128bit unsigned integer but there is no such data type in VBA.
So as far as I know you can't manipulate IPv6 addresses as integers.

Answer (score -1):

I have some Excel IP functions which you should be able to start with.

```
=SubnetIPv4(IPv4,Bits,Offset)      =IsIPv4(IPv4)
IP Address  Bits Offset Result        Result
10.11.12.13  26    0    10.11.12.0    TRUE
Notes:
Macros must be enabled
IPv4 is a string representing an IPv4 address in dotted decimal format
Bits is an integer (0 to 32) representing the number of mask bits
Offset is an integer representing the host address offset into the subnet
Using Offset 0 will retun a subnet for any IP address
Using IPv4 of 255.255.255.255 and Offset 0 will retun a mask of Bits size

=SubnetIPv6(IPv6,Bits,Offset)                              =IsIPv6(IPv6)
IP Address                Bits Offset Result                   Result
fe80::1dce:e8b3:1a14:2c3b  10    ::   FE80:0:0:0:0:0:0:0        TRUE
Notes:
Macros must be enabled
IPv6 is a string representing an IPv6 address in standard format (leading 0s are optional and :: works)
Bits is an integer (0 to 128) representing the number of mask bits
Offset is a string representing the host address offset into the subnet in standard format (leading 0s are optional and :: works)
Using Offset equivalent to 0 (::, ::0, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, etc.) will retun a subnet for any IP address
Using IPv6 of FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF and Offset equivalent to 0 will retun a mask of Bits size


Function CountStr(Source As String, Target As String) As Integer
    Dim c, i As Integer
    c = 0
    If Not ((Source = "") Or (Target = "")) Then
        For i = 1 To Len(Source)
            If Mid(Source, i, Len(Target)) = Target Then
                c = c + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
    CountStr = c
End Function


Function SubnetIPv4(IPv4 As String, Bits As Integer, Offset As Long) As String

    Dim a() As String
    Dim c, d, i As Integer
    Dim m As Long
    Dim s As String

    If IPv4 = "" Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If

    c = CountStr(IPv4, ".")
    If c <> 3 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If

    c = CountStr(IPv4, "..")
    If c > 1 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If

    If (Left(IPv4, 1) = ".") Or (Right(IPv4, 1) = ".") Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If

    a = Split(IPv4, ".")
    If UBound(a) <> 3 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If

    On Error GoTo InvalidIPv4
    For i = 0 To 3
        If (Len(a(i)) > 0) And (Len(a(i)) < 4) Then
            a(i) = CInt(a(i))
            If (a(i) < 0) Or (a(i) > 255) Then
                GoTo InvalidIPv4
            End If
        Else
            GoTo InvalidIPv4
        End If
    Next

    If (Bits < 0) Or (Bits > 32) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If

    c = Bits Mod 8
    d = Bits \ 8
    If (Bits <> 0) And (c = 0) Then
        c = 8
        d = d - 1
    End If
    m = 0
    For i = 0 To 7
        m = m * 2
        If c > 0 Then
            m = m + 1
            c = c - 1
        End If
    Next
    a(d) = CStr(CLng(a(d)) And m)
    For i = d + 1 To 3
        a(i) = "0"
    Next

    If Offset < 0 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If

    m = 0
    For i = 1 To (32 - Bits)
        m = m * 2
        m = m + 1
    Next
    If Offset > m Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If

    m = Offset
    For i = 3 To 0 Step -1
        a(i) = a(i) + (m Mod 256)
        m = m \ 256
    Next

    s = ""
    For i = 0 To 3
        s = s + CStr(a(i)) + "."
    Next
    s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)

    SubnetIPv4 = s
    Exit Function

InvalidIPv4:
    Error (3)

End Function



Function IsIPv4(IPv4 As String) As Boolean

    Dim s As String

    On Error GoTo InvalidIPv4
    s = SubnetIPv4(IPv4, 32, 0)

    IsIPv4 = True
    Exit Function

InvalidIPv4:
    IsIPv4 = False

End Function

Function SubnetIPv6(IPv6 As String, Bits As Integer, Offset As String) As String

    Dim a() As String
    Dim c, d, i As Integer
    Dim m As Long
    Dim s, t As String

    If IPv6 = "" Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    c = CountStr(IPv6, ":")
    If (c < 2) Or (c > 8) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    d = CountStr(IPv6, "::")
    If d > 1 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    If (Left(IPv6, 1) = ":") And (Not (Left(IPv6, 2) = "::")) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    If (Right(IPv6, 1) = ":") And (Not (Right(IPv6, 2) = "::")) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    s = IPv6
    If d = 1 Then
        If Left(s, 2) = "::" Then
            s = "0" + s
        End If
        If Right(s, 2) = "::" Then
            s = s + "0"
        End If
        t = ":"
        For i = c To 7
            t = t + "0:"
        Next
        s = Replace(s, "::", t)
    End If

    a = Split(s, ":")
    If UBound(a) <> 7 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    On Error GoTo InvalidIPv6
    For i = 0 To 7
        If (Len(a(i)) > 0) And (Len(a(i)) < 5) Then
            a(i) = WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(a(i))
        Else
            GoTo InvalidIPv6
        End If
    Next

    If (Bits < 0) Or (Bits > 128) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    c = Bits Mod 16
    d = Bits \ 16
    If (Bits <> 0) And (c = 0) Then
        c = 16
        d = d - 1
    End If
    m = 0
    For i = 0 To 15
        m = m * 2
        If c > 0 Then
          m = m + 1
          c = c - 1
        End If
    Next
    a(d) = CStr(CLng(a(d)) And m)
    For i = d + 1 To 7
        a(i) = "0"
    Next

    If Offset = "" Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    c = CountStr(Offset, ":")
    If (c < 2) Or (c > 8) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    d = CountStr(Offset, "::")
    If d > 1 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    If (Left(Offset, 1) = ":") And (Not (Left(Offset, 2) = "::")) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    If (Right(Offset, 1) = ":") And (Not (Right(Offset, 2) = "::")) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    s = Offset
    If d = 1 Then
        If Left(s, 2) = "::" Then
            s = "0" + s
        End If
        If Right(s, 2) = "::" Then
            s = s + "0"
        End If
        t = ":"
        For i = c To 7
            t = t + "0:"
        Next
        s = Replace(s, "::", t)
    End If

    b = Split(s, ":")
    If UBound(b) <> 7 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    On Error GoTo InvalidIPv6
    For i = 0 To 7
        If (Len(b(i)) > 0) And (Len(b(i)) < 5) Then
            b(i) = WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(b(i))
        Else
            GoTo InvalidIPv6
        End If
    Next

    c = Bits Mod 16
    d = Bits \ 16
    If (Bits <> 0) And (c = 0) Then
        c = 16
        d = d - 1
    End If
    m = 0
    For i = 0 To 15
        m = m * 2
        If c > 0 Then
          m = m + 1
          c = c - 1
        End If
    Next

    For i = 0 To d - 1
        If b(i) <> "0" Then
            GoTo InvalidIPv6
        End If
    Next
    If b(d) <> CStr(CLng(b(d)) And m) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If

    For i = 7 To d Step -1
        a(i) = CStr(CLng(a(i)) + CLng(b(i)))
    Next

    s = ""
    For i = 0 To 7
        s = s + WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(a(i)) + ":"
    Next
    s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)

    SubnetIPv6 = s
    Exit Function

InvalidIPv6:
    Error (3)

End Function



Function IsIPv6(IPv6 As String) As Boolean

    Dim s As String

    On Error GoTo InvalidIPv6
    s = SubnetIPv6(IPv6, 128, "::")

    IsIPv6 = True
    Exit Function

InvalidIPv6:
    IsIPv6 = False

End Function
```

Comment: You haven't explained what these functions do and how it solves the OP's problem of representing an IPv6 string as a decimal value.

Comment: I'm not sure what I can explain. These functions are how I got them. The OP expressed a desire to create a custom Excel formula. There are 2 functions each for IPv4 and IPv6 to validate and calculate addresses. I found them useful, and the OP may be able to do something with the code.

Comment: I can't really explain everything. I added something that shows what I figured out for how to use these.

Comment: Thank you.. I will have a look at the code and see if I can get it to work. Havent had the time yet!

Comment: it does not give a decimal value of ipv6.. so i can check if ipv6 is correct that is fine, but i still dont have a decimal value to compare to range of ipv6 number...

Comment: I don't know much about VBA, but I seriously doubt you can get a 128-bit unsigned-integer value, and that seems to be what you want. It looks like it is creating an array of 8 integers to represent the IPv6 value. Those are the eight words of up to 65536 each of which you spoke in an earlier comment.  I think that is as close to the decimal value, that you asked for, as you are going to get.

Comment: I can use the SubnetIPv6 function to see if an address is in a range. A range is a subnet, and that function turns an address into a subnet, so I would just check to see if the address (reduced to s subnet) matches the subnet. I use it that way all the time to see if addresses are in a valid address range.